# Losing DropDownList Items in Footer on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, viewstate

I'm trying to use GridView in my web app but it's driving me crazy. Always losing DropDownList items in footer after any PostBack. The only way everything went smoothly was when I Get the list of Countries from the database in any event and bind the Countries_List in footer. Is that normal ?

I tried to debug my code, the debugger executes the lines in RowDataBound and Bind the DropDownList but still the DropDownList gets back to me empty!!

My Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using BL;
using DL;

namespace BulkShop.admin
{
    public partial class ManageCities : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                GrdVw.DataSource = CitiesBL.GetAll();
                GrdVw.DataBind();

                DropDownList countryListNew = (DropDownList)GrdVw.FooterRow.FindControl("countries_DrpDwnLst");
                countryListNew.DataSource = CountriesBL.GetAll();
                countryListNew.DataBind();

                //if (CitiesBL.GetAll().Count == 0)
                //{
                //    Country cnt = new Country();
                //    City c = new City();
                //    c.ID = 1;
                //    c.Name = "Empty";
                //    cnt.ID = 1;
                //    cnt.Name = "Empty";
                //    c.Country = cnt;
                //    List<City> cities = new List<City>();
                //    cities.Add(c);

                //    GrdVw.DataSource = cities;
                //    GrdVw.DataBind();
                //}
            }
        }

        protected void GrdVw_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {
                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    DropDownList countryListNew = (DropDownList)GrdVw.FooterRow.FindControl("countries_DrpDwnLst");
                    countryListNew.DataSource = CountriesBL.GetAll();
                    countryListNew.DataBind();

                }
            }

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
                {

                    //do the binding for the normal rows

                    DropDownList countryList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("countries_DrpDwnLst");

                    //bind dropdownlist
                    countryList.DataSource = CountriesBL.GetAll();
                    countryList.DataBind();


                    City a = (City)e.Row.DataItem;

                    countryList.SelectedValue = a.Country.ID.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void GrdVw_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            GrdVw.EditIndex = -1;
            GrdVw.DataSource = CitiesBL.GetAll();
            GrdVw.DataBind();
        }
        protected void Delete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Msg = "";
            bool success = false;

            LinkButton lnkRemove = (LinkButton)sender;
            int cityId = Convert.ToInt32(lnkRemove.CommandArgument);
            GrdVw.EditIndex = -1;

            //UPDATE DL METHOD
            success = CitiesBL.Delete(cityId, out Msg);

            //Display Msg
            grdVwMsg_Lbl.Text = Msg;

            if (success)
            {
                //GridView1.DataBind();
                GrdVw.DataSource = CitiesBL.GetAll();
                GrdVw.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void GrdVw_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            grdVwMsg_Lbl.Text = "";

            GrdVw.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            GrdVw.DataSource = CitiesBL.GetAll();
            GrdVw.DataBind();
        }

        protected void GrdVw_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            string Msg = "";
            bool success = false;

            int cityId = Convert.ToInt32(GrdVw.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GrdVw.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            TextBox cityName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("name_TxtBx");
            DropDownList countries = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("countries_DrpDwnLst");
            City c = new City();
            Country cnt = new Country();
            c.ID = cityId;
            c.Name = cityName.Text;
            cnt.ID = Convert.ToInt32(countries.SelectedValue);
            c.Country = cnt;

            //UPDATE DL METHOD
            success = CitiesBL.Update(c, out Msg);

            //Display Msg
            grdVwMsg_Lbl.Text = Msg;

            if (success)
            {
                cityName.Text = "";
                countries.SelectedIndex = 0;
                GrdVw.EditIndex = -1;

                //GridView1.DataBind();
                GrdVw.DataSource = CitiesBL.GetAll();
                GrdVw.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void AddNew(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get Data From The Form
            TextBox newCity = (TextBox)GrdVw.FooterRow.FindControl("newCityName_TxtBx");
            DropDownList countries = (DropDownList)GrdVw.FooterRow.FindControl("countries_DrpDwnLst");
            City c = new City();
            Country cnt = new Country();

            c.Name = newCity.Text.Trim();
            cnt.ID = Convert.ToInt32(countries.SelectedValue);
            c.Country = cnt;

            //Create & Initiate Local Variables
            string msg = "";
            bool success = false;

            success = CitiesBL.Add(c, out msg);
            grdVwMsg_Lbl.Text = msg;

            if (success)
            {
                newCity.Text = "";
                countries.SelectedIndex = 0;

                //GridView1.DataBind();
                GrdVw.DataSource = CitiesBL.GetAll();
                GrdVw.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My ASPX Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin/admin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ManageCities.aspx.cs" Inherits="BulkShop.admin.ManageCities" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="grdVwMsg_Lbl" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
    <asp:GridView ID="GrdVw" ShowFooter="True" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowCancelingEdit="GrdVw_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="GrdVw_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GrdVw_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GrdVw_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ID" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox  ID="name_TxtBx"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="name_Lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="newCityName_TxtBx" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="countries_DrpDwnLst" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="countryName_Lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country.Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="countries_DrpDwnLst" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("ID")%>' OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you want to delete?')" Text = "Delete" OnClick = "Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick = "AddNew" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField  ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Why you have two dropdown list with same id `countries_DrpDwnLst`?

Comment: It's under diffrent scopes. Firat one in the DataRow and second one in FooterRow. It even compiles no problem

Comment: @RahulSingh do you have any other guesses to why this is happening ?

Comment: @iKashef, have you solve this problem already? because i am facing the same problem...

Comment: @Wen21 sorry for the late reply. I actually re-designed my page and replaced the footer with a separate div for creating new entities which I think is a better design. However to solve the problem I think what I did was bind the footer controls on each postback.